# How to exclude source folder from jar file

Tags: java, gradle, jar

How can I exclude a source folder from a jar file using Gradle Kotlin DSL?

The source sets are

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs("src/main/java")
            srcDirs("src/util/java")
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to exclude `src/util/java` from Jars.

I tried

```
tasks {
  withType<Jar> {
    exclude("src/util/java/**")
  }
}
```

but that does ot work because the string likely does not contain the source folder.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter in the compile task.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    exclude '**/util/**/*.java'
}
```

but this is appropriate if you looking to exclude some specific files.

If the whole src folder (like util) is to be excluded, it would be better redefine the `sourceSets.main.java` to only src folders you need - for that module

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Well, I would like to have the files compiled and also to be able to run them in IntelliJ and to unit test them. Should I go for a separate source set?